# Why is `True is False == False`, False in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why is it that these statements work as expected when brackets are used:

```
>>> (True is False) == False
True

>>> True is (False == False)
True
```

**But** it returns `False` when there are no brackets?

```
>>> True is False == False
False
```

Comment: Apparently you got into one of the few dark corners of Python syntax (i.e. places where the result is quite surprising).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Based on python [*documentation*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) about operator precedence :

> Note that comparisons, membership tests, and identity tests, all have the same precedence and have a left-to-right **chaining** feature as described in the Comparisons section.

So actually you have a chained statement like following :

```
>>> (True is False) and (False==False)
False
```

You can assume that the central object will be shared between 2 operations and other objects (False in this case).

And note that its also true for all Comparisons, including membership tests and identity tests operations which are following operands :

```
in, not in, is, is not, <, <=, >, >=, !=, ==
```

Example :

```
>>> 1 in [1,2] == True
False
```

Answer (score 17):

Python has a unique transitive property when it comes to the comparison operators. It will be easier to see in a simpler case.

```
if 1 < x < 2:
    # Do something
```

This does what it looks like. It checks if 1 < x and if x < 2. The same thing is happening in your non-parenthesized code.

```
>>> True is False == False
False
```

It is checking whether True is False **and** False == False, only one of which is true.

Comment: Ahhh! I've used `1 < x < 2` and just thought it was a special case, I didn't realise that it applied to other operators too.

Answer (score 8):

This is a double inequality which gets expanded as `(True is False) and (False == False)`. See for instance [What is the operator precedence when writing a double inequality in Python (explicitly in the code, and how can this be overridden for arrays?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12658197/what-is-the-operator-precedence-when-writing-a-double-inequality-in-python-expl)

Comment: So in short, this is a bug? It seems very counter-intuitive.

Comment: In other hand, you can write `0 < 0.25 < 0.5` which would give a weird result in other languages.

Comment: No, it isn't a bug - it's the intended operation of the language surprising you

Answer (score 2):

Python interprets multiple (in)equalities the way you would expect in Math:

In Math `a = b = c` mean all `a = b`, `b = c` and `a = c`.

So `True is False == False` means `True == False` and `False == False` and `True == False`, which is `False`.

For boolean constants, `is` is equivalent to `==`.

Comment: Actually, `a is b == c` only means `(a is b) and (b == c)`: `a` and `c` are not compared. Consider `0.0 == 0 is 0`.

Comment: @Mauris I meant that a is b and b is c implies a is c. I was only giving a simple way to determine the result not how its processed

Answer (score 1):

**Python performs chaining if it encounters operators of same precedence when evaluating an expression.**

> comparisons, including tests, which all have the same precedence
>   **chain** from left to right

The below mentioned operators have the same precedence.

```
in, not in, is, is not, <, <=, >, >=, <>, !=, ==
```

So, when Python tries to evaluate the expression `True is False == False`, it encounters the operators `is` and `==`  which have the same precedence, so it performs chaining from left to right.

So, the expression `True is False == False` is actually evaluated as:

```
(True is False) and (False == False)
```

giving `False` as the output.