# Why does "not(True) in [False, True]" return False?

Tags: python, operator-precedence, comparison-operators

If I do this:

```
>>> False in [False, True]
True
```

That returns `True`. Simply because `False` is in the list.

But if I do:

```
>>> not(True) in [False, True]
False
```

That returns `False`. Whereas `not(True)` is equal to `False`:

```
>>> not(True)
False
```

Why?

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31354429/why-is-true-is-false-false-false-in-python/31354514#31354514

Comment: your parentheses are confusing in `not(True) in [False, True]`

Answer (score 750, accepted):

**Operator precedence** <sup>[2.x](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence), [3.x](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)</sup>. The precedence of `not` is lower than that of `in`. So it is equivalent to:

```
>>> not ((True) in [False, True])
False
```

This is what you want:

```
>>> (not True) in [False, True]
True
```

---

As @Ben points out: It's recommended to never write `not(True)`, prefer `not True`. The former makes it look like a function call, while `not` is an operator, not a function.

Comment: @Texom512: I would also recommend never writing `not(True)`; prefer `not True`. The first makes it look like a function call, which is where your confusion came from; if `not` was a function, then `not(True) in ...` couldn't possibly be `not ((True) in ...)`. You have to know it's an operator (or you end up in situations like this), so you should write it like an operator, not disguise it as a function.

Comment: Also, if you're going to use spacing to indicate precedence for the benefit of the reader, first make sure you're right. It's probably OK to write `a + b*c + d`, it's very bad to write `a+b * c+d`. So `not(True)` is bad by that measure too.

Comment: Actually, **never** write `not True`. Write `False` instead.

Comment: Presumably in real life you wouldn't be writing `not True`, you'd be writing something like `not myfunc(x,y,z)` where `myfunc` is some function that returns `True` or `False`.

Comment: @YuHao I would enjoy your explanation as to [why you reversed my edits](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31421411/revisions), as I believe they help readers better understand what's going on.

Comment: @YuHao yes, the parentheses in `(True)` are redundant. However, they were in the original question, so taking them out actually makes it more confusing, since it's harder to tell how your answer relates to the OP's question. Additionally, they weren't in your recommended fix ("This is what you want:"), so I wasn't intending them to be something anyone SHOULD do, just a visual aid to relate it to the problem code.

Comment: @BenC.R.Leggiero That's what I did in [the original answer](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/31421411/1), and others have corrected it. The current version is clear enough for me, I don't think it's hard to understand without the redundant parentheses, since the key problem has been pointed out, understanding the rest is a programmer's basic skill.

Answer (score 78):

**`not x in y`** is evaluated as **`x not in y`**

You can see exactly what's happening by disassembling the code.  The first case works as you expect:

```
>>> x = lambda: False in [False, True]
>>> dis.dis(x)
  1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (False)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (False)
              6 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (True)
              9 BUILD_LIST               2
             12 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
             15 RETURN_VALUE
```

The second case, evaluates to `True not in [False, True]`, which is `False` clearly:

```
>>> x = lambda: not(True) in [False, True]
>>> dis.dis(x)
  1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (True)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (False)
              6 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (True)
              9 BUILD_LIST               2
             12 COMPARE_OP               7 (not in)
             15 RETURN_VALUE        
>>>
```

What you wanted to express instead was `(not(True)) in [False, True]`, which as expected is `True`, and you can see why:

```
>>> x = lambda: (not(True)) in [False, True]
>>> dis.dis(x)
  1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (True)
              3 UNARY_NOT           
              4 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (False)
              7 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (True)
             10 BUILD_LIST               2
             13 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
             16 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: There is always a guy with `dis` but this is a very valuable answer because it shows that actually `not in` is used

Comment: Bytecode is an implementation detail of the CPython interpreter.  This is a CPython answer to a Python question, in fact it can be better answered from the language reference directly.

Comment: @wim I would argue that the bytecode implementation is not as important as the actual disassembly. Other implementations are guaranteed to generate something functionally identical, so understanding one disassembly offers enough insight to understand the "why" and not the lowlevel "how".

Answer (score 37):

Operator precedence. `in` binds more tightly than `not`, so your expression is equivalent to `not((True) in [False, True])`.

Answer (score 34):

It's all about [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html) (`in` is stronger than `not`). But it can be easily corrected by adding parentheses at the right place:

```
(not(True)) in [False, True]  # prints true
```

writing:

```
not(True) in [False, True]
```

is the same like:

```
not((True) in [False, True])
```

which looks if `True` is in the list and returns the "not" of the result.

Answer (score 14):

It is evaluating as `not True in [False, True]`, which returns `False` because `True` is in `[False, True]`

If you try

```
>>>(not(True)) in [False, True]
True
```

You get the expected result.

Answer (score 13):

Alongside the other answers that mentioned the precedence of `not` is lower than `in`, actually your statement is equivalent to :

```
not (True in [False, True])
```

But note that if you don't separate your condition from the other ones, python will use 2 roles (`precedence` or `chaining`) in order to separate that, and in this case python used precedence. Also, note that if you want to separate a condition you need to put all the condition in parenthesis not just the object or value :

```
(not True) in [False, True]
```

---

But as mentioned, there is another modification by python on operators that is **chaining**:

Based on python [*documentation*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) :

> Note that comparisons, membership tests, and identity tests, all have the same precedence and have a left-to-right **chaining** feature as described in the Comparisons section.

For example the result of following statement is `False`:

```
>>> True == False in [False, True]
False
```

Because python will chain the statements like following :

```
(True == False) and (False in [False, True])
```

Which exactly is `False and True` that is `False`.

You can assume that the central object will be shared between 2 operations and other objects (False in this case).

And note that its also true for all Comparisons, including membership tests and identity tests operations which are following operands :

```
in, not in, is, is not, <, <=, >, >=, !=, ==
```

Example :

```
>>> 1 in [1,2] == True
False
```

Another famous example is number range :

```
7<x<20
```

which is equal to :

```
7<x and x<20
```

Answer (score 6):

Let's see it as a collection containment checking operation: `[False, True]` is a list containing some elements.

The expression `True in [False, True]` returns `True`, as `True` is an element contained in the list.

Therefore, `not True in [False, True]` gives the "boolean opposite", `not` result of the above expression (without any parentheses to preserve precedence, as `in` has greater precedence than `not` operator).
Therefore, `not True` will result `False`.

On the other hand, `(not True) in [False, True]`, is equal to `False in [False, True]`, which is `True` (`False` is contained in the list).

Answer (score 6):

To clarify on some of the other answers, adding parentheses *after* a unary operator does not change its precedence. `not(True)` does not make `not` bind more tightly to `True`. It's just a redundant set of parentheses around `True`. It's much the same as `(True) in [True, False]`. The parentheses don't do anything.  If you want the binding to be more tight, you have to put the parentheses around the whole expression, meaning both the operator and the operand, i.e., `(not True) in [True, False]`.

To see this another way, consider

```
>>> -2**2
-4
```

`**` binds more tightly than `-`, which is why you get the negative of two squared, not the square of negative two (which would be positive four).

What if you did want the square of negative two? Obviously, you'd add parentheses:

```
>>> (-2)**2
4
```

However, it's not reasonable to expect the following to give `4`

```
>>> -(2)**2
-4
```

because `-(2)` is the same as `-2`. The parentheses do absolutely nothing. `not(True)` is exactly the same.

Comment: One of the stranger gotcha's of Perl is that it does indeed change the precedence when the following `(` is present, even for built-in operators, so that `return ($x+$y)*$z` means `(return($x+$y))*$z`. So it's understandable that someone who's used to Perl might get tripped up by this.