# Yoda condition with "not x is None"

Tags: python, if-statement, equivalent

The previous dev has left a really strange `not x is None` yoda condition in the code:

```
>>> x = None
>>> not x is None
False
>>> x = 1
>>> not x is None
True
```

After some testing, I seem the same output as `x is not None`.

```
>>> x = None
>>> not x is None
False
>>> x is not None
False
>>> x = 1
>>> not x is None
True
>>> x is not None
True
```

**Is `not x is None` always equivalent to `x is not None`?**

To break down the condition, **is it `not (x is None)` or `(not x) is None`**? Or will the former always be equivalent to the latter?

Comment: It's all about the operator precedence. Read this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31421379/why-does-nottrue-in-false-true-return-false/31458009#31458009

Comment: Yup according to the [document](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence), **not** has lower precedence than comparison **is**. So your former assumption should be correct.

Comment: A “Yoda condition” would be `None is x`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `is` has higher precendence than `not`, then the expressions are equivalent:

In case `x = None`:
`x is None` evaluates to `True`, and `not x is None` evaluates to `False`
In case `x = 1`:
`x is None` evaluates to `False`, and `not x is None` evaluates to `True`

In case `x = None`:
`x is not None` evaluates to `False`
In case `x = 1`:
`x is not None` evaluates to `True`.

Therefore, even though the actions are not syntactically equivalent, the results are equivalent.

This is the AST of `not x is None`:

[image]

This is the AST of `x is not None`:

[image]

As can be seen in the second diagram, the inner node is the compare node, and therefore `x is None` is evaluated before the `not`.

Regarding actual evaluation of the expression, it seems that python creates the same bytecode for both. It can be seen in this example:

```
def foo(x):
    x is not None


def bar(x):
    not x is None

import dis
dis.dis(foo)
dis.dis(bar)
```

As both generate:

```
      0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
      3 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
      6 COMPARE_OP               9 (is not)
      9 POP_TOP             
     10 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
     13 RETURN_VALUE
```

Answer (score 1):

`is not` is (I believe, the only) two-keyword operator in Python, and `x is not y` is entirely equivalent to `not x is y`. The same result will also be returned by `id(x) != id(y)`. The canonical spelling for best reader comprehension would be `x is not y`.

Comment: `not in` is another.

Comment: This is why I try to avoid being too bombastic about my beliefs - there's usually someone better-informed or smarter to correct me. Thanks!