# Why does `None is None is None` return True?

Tags: python

Today, in an interview, the CTO asked me what looks like an easy question,

What does this statement return ? :

```
None is None is None
```

I thought Python executed the first operation `None is None` and would return `True`. After that, it would compare `True is None` which would return `False`. But, to my surprise, the right answer is `True`. I am trying to find answer to this question, but after a couple of days searching I didn't find anything. Can someone explain why this happens?

Comment: Python comparison operators chain. `None is None is None` is equivalent to `None is None and None is None`.

Comment: to get the behaviour you expect, you would have to use parentheses: `if (None is None) is None`.

Comment: interesting though. I never knew this could happen and I would have expected the same thing knowing what the `is` operator does...

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Is this really a duplicate? It is not the same question. The answers are the same, but the question isn't.

Comment: [The](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9284350/why-does-1-in-1-0-true-evaluate-to-false) [precedent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31354429/why-is-true-is-false-false-false-in-python/31354499) for these sorts of questions seems to be to use that particular one as a dup target.

Comment: Basically, I think that the _questioning process_ (the causes that brought him to ask this question) is significantly different from the other questions. This should be considered when flagging for duplicates, because it's the basis of which brings people here.

Comment: @scharette: The difference in the questioning process seems to amount to "I found this in the Queue.py source" vs "The CTO I was interviewing with asked me this". It seems entirely appropriate to dupe-close this question.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The bytecode shows that two comparisons are being performed here with the middle being duplicated:

```
>>> import dis
>>> def a():
...     return None is None is None
... 
>>> dis.dis(a)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              3 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              6 DUP_TOP
              7 ROT_THREE
              8 COMPARE_OP               8 (is)
             11 JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP    21
             14 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             17 COMPARE_OP               8 (is)
             20 RETURN_VALUE
        >>   21 ROT_TWO
             22 POP_TOP
             23 RETURN_VALUE
```

As stated in the [docs for comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) this is because these operators chain together.

`a op b op c` will be translated to `a op b and b op c` (note `b` is duplicated in the bytecode as shown above)

Answer (score 34):

As some people comments, *Python comparisons can be chained*.

For the sake of explanation, when chaining, Python actually **ANDs** the expressions.

**The rationale behind this**, is that expressions like `a < b < c` have the interpretation that is conventional in mathematics. Hence the confusion of your particular expression `None is None is None` where *identy* operators are involved.

So basically, this would translate to:

```
(None is None) and (None is None)
```

which is clearly `True`

Here is another example in the Python [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#comparisons)

**Further Information**

Especially since this was an interview question, it is important to note that this is not a general behavior shared among all languages.

As it is stated in the documentation I linked,

> Unlike C, all comparison operations in Python have the same priority,
>   which is lower than that of any arithmetic, shifting or bitwise
>   operation.

So, let's consider the `10 > x > 2` expression (since `is` operator is not valid in C).

**C's translation** (because of [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence))

```
((10 > x) > 2)
```

**Python's translation**

```
(10 > x) and (x > 2)
```

Comment: I like this answer because it explains the rationale behind the behavior: ***expressions like a < b < c have the interpretation that is conventional in mathematics***. Seeing how it is implemented in bytecode, in my opinion, explains nothing that would allow me to be able to extrapolate to other cases.

Comment: @Jim Your comment is really appreciated. For future users I made sure to put more emphasis on that point because it is indeed the true reason behind this behavior. `None is None is None` is a particular misleading statement following this logic since no mathematics is involved..

Comment: Although it's true there's no *mathematics* involved, the result still matches colloquial usage. For instance, "a fool is a fool is a fool" might be used for emphasis, while "an idiot is a fool is a nitwit" would imply equivalence between all three terms.

Comment: @IMSoP You're right, _mathematics_ wasn't the good term to use. See my answer I actually meant that _identy_ operators are used which is really confusing compared to the same behavior when using _comparison_ operators like `<` if that make sense.

Comment: I'm not sure it's any more or less surprising with identity operators; they're just another type of comparison. As I say, we'd use "is" that way in English, and a mathematician might well write `x = y = z`, or `x ≡ y ≡ z`, etc. I think it's just surprising because programming languages don't normally have operators that behave this way.

Answer (score 10):

`is` is a comparison operator, [as seen in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons):

> ```
> comparison    ::=  or_expr ( comp_operator or_expr )*
> comp_operator ::=  "<" | ">" | "==" | ">=" | "<=" | "!="
>                    | "is" ["not"] | ["not"] "in"
> ```

So just like the other comparison operators, it can be chained arbitrarily. So

```
a = b = c = None
a is b is c
```

is equivalent to

```
(a is b) and (b is c)
```

Comment: Note that assignment is not a comparison with the same semantics. Specifically `a = b = c` is not evaluated in the same was as `a is b is c` or similar. `a = b = c` works from right to left. Whereas `a comp b comp c` is transformed into `a comp b` and `b comp c`. `a = b = c` is transformed into `b = c; a = b`

Comment: @shuttle87 Yes.. I simply wrote `a = b = c = None` for the subsequent example.