# I have a confusion with regard to print(10==10==True) and print(10==10 and True) in Python

Tags: python

```
print(2==2==True)
```

gives the result : `False`

so my query is why it doesn't give answer as True?

Where as :

```
print(2==2 and True)
```

gives the result: `True`

can anyone give a satisfactory answer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is `True is False == False`, False in Python? \[duplicate\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31354429/why-is-true-is-false-false-false-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

When you do:

```
print(a == b == c)
```

You are checking if the values of `a`, `b`, and `c` are the same. Since `2` is NOT equal to `True`, the statement is false, and the output of

```
print(2 == 2 == True)
```

will be `False`.

However, when you do:

```
print(2 == 2 and True)
```

You are checking that if BOTH `2 == 2` and `True` have the boolean values of `True`, then you will print out `True`, and otherwise `False`. Since 2 does equal 2, the expression `2 == 2` is `True`. Thus, `True and True` is `True`, so the output will be `True`.

Let me know if you have sny further questions or clarifications!

Comment: To add to this, you can run `print((2 == 2) == True)` to check if 2 == 2 was True as it will first check whether 2 is 2, before comparing the result (True / False) with the True statement at the end. Although i'm not seeing why this would be necessary.

Comment: so in the first scenario 2==2 basically will imply 2==True  if my query is right?

Comment: 2 == 2 is the same as True, but 2 == 2 == True is asking "are 2, 2, and True all the same values?"

Answer (score 1):

From python docs:

> #### [Comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons):
>
> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., `x < y <= z` is equivalent to `x < y and y <= z`, except that y is evaluated only once (but in both cases z is not evaluated at all when `x < y` is found to be false).
>
> Formally, if `a`, `b`, `c`, …, `y`, `z` are expressions and `op1`, `op2`, …, `opN` are comparison operators, then `a op1 b op2 c ... y opN z` is equivalent to `a op1 b and b op2 c and ... y opN z`, except that each expression is evaluated at most once.

In your first example,

```
print(2 == 2 == True) # This is in the form `a op b op c`
```

is equivalent to `2 == 2 and 2 == True`. which is `True and False`.

---

In your second example, there would be no chaining since `and` is not comparison operator.

```
print(2 == 2 and True)
```

is equivalent to `2 == 2 and True`, which is `True and True`.

---

If you want to force evaluation of an expression first then put the expression inside `()`.

```
print((2 == 2) == True)
print((2 == 2) and True)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first Case `2==2==True` You are testing three conditions which is like.

1. `2==2 => True`
2. `2==True => False`
3. `True==2 => False` (Don't need check because if first 2 fulfills then this one is also true

and in Second Case `2==2 and True' You are testing two conditions which is like.

1. `2==2 => True`
2. `True and True => True`

Answer (score 0):

The == operator compares the value or equality of objects.
print(2==2==True) means you are comparing three objects together. 2 equals 2 as both values are equal but 2 and 2 is value whereas True is equality so overall value becomes false.

print(2==2 and True) means you are comparing equality of 2==2 and True. 2 equals 2 as both values are equal and equality is True. True is equality so True and True equality becomes true.

Comment: What does "2 and 2 is value whereas True is equality" mean?