# Inequalities and Parenthesis in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements, inequality

So in python, truth conditions can be easily checked and with parenthesis it prioritize the order of true conditions, e.g. these are easy to understand:

```
>>> 3 > 2
True
>>> (3 > 2) is True
True
```

But what does these mean, I couldn't grasp the logic of why they return False/True:

```
>>> 3 > 2 is True
False
>>> 3 > (2 is True)
True
>>> 5 < 3 is False > 2 is True
False
>>> 5 < 3 is False is True > 2 is True
False
>>> 3 < 5 is True is True > 2 is True
False
>>> 3 < 5 is True is True > 2 is True is not False is True
False
>>> 3 < 5 is True is (True > 2 is True is not False) is True
False
>>> 3 < 5 is True is (True > (2 is True) is not False) is True
False
>>> (3 < 5 is True is True) > 2 is (True is not False is True)
False
```

I know these are not pythonic conditions but **how should I understand them? Is it still from left to right?**

**Or does `is True` or/and `is False` takes presidence?**

Comment: I feel like this is a duplicate of [What is the operator precedence when writing a double inequality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12658197). However, I'll let you make the call. Otherwise, leave the comment as additional information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can analyse each of those cases with `dis` module to figure out exactly what's happening. For example:

```
In [1]: import dis
In [2]: def test():
   ...:     return 3 > 2 is True
   ...: 
In [3]: dis.dis(test)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (3)
              3 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
              6 DUP_TOP             
              7 ROT_THREE           
              8 COMPARE_OP               4 (>)
             11 JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP    21
             14 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (True)
             17 COMPARE_OP               8 (is)
             20 RETURN_VALUE        
        >>   21 ROT_TWO             
             22 POP_TOP             
             23 RETURN_VALUE
```

That means the stack looks like this after each step:

```
 0: 3
 3: 3 2
 6: 3 2 2
 7: 2 3 2
 8: 2 True
11: 2
14: 2 True
17: False (comparison was: "2 is True")
20: (False is returned)
```

<strike>To me, it looks like a bug in Python to be honest. Maybe there's some good explanation of why this happens, but I'd report it upstream.</strike>

Just to rewrite it in equivalent way, the code does:

```
if 3 > 2:
    if 2 is True:
        return True
return False
```

Edit: Maybe it actually makes some weird kind of sense. Consider how checking chained inequalities works:

```
3 > 2 > 1  ==  3 > 2 and 2 > 1
```

If it generalises to:

```
x op1 y op2 z == x op1 y and y op2 z
```

that would explain the result.

Edit2: This actually matches documentation. Have a look at chained comparisons: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in

```
comparison    ::=  or_expr ( comp_operator or_expr )*
comp_operator ::=  "<" | ">" | "==" | ">=" | "<=" | "<>" | "!="
                   | "is" ["not"] | ["not"] "in"
```

`is` is considered just as good comparison as `>`, so the standard expansion for multiple comparisons is applied.

Other comparisons should be clear now. The only strange new detail needed is: `True == 1`, `False == 0`, so `3 > False` in `3 > (2 is True)`. Most others can be explained with the expansions. For example:

```
5  <     3     is       False       >     2     is True  == False
(5 < 3) and (3 is False) and (False > 2) and (2 is True) == False
```

Comment: just wondering, what does the `JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP` operation supposed to signify?

Comment: Literally what the name suggests :) If top of stack is false it jumps. If not, it pops the value.

Comment: sorry, I should be more specific: what does it mean to `JUMP`?

Comment: It mean the stack is not affected and the program starts executing from the referenced label. Here it's `JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP 21`, so if the top of stack was "False", the next bytecode executed would be `21 ROT_TWO`.

Comment: Thanks @viraptor, now it's starting to make sense but it's still a little hard to get through these conditions without a clear mind =)

Answer (score 2):

`Boolean` type in python is a subtype of `int`. So `True` is actually 1 and `False` is 0.

All comparison operations in Python have the same priority (`>`, `<`, `>=`, `<=`, `==`, `!=`, `is [not]`, `[not] in`).

> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., `x < y <= z` is equivalent to `x < y and y <= z`, except that y is evaluated only once (but in both cases z is not evaluated at all when `x < y` is found to be false).
>
> Formally, if `a`, `b`, `c`, ..., `y`, `z` are expressions and `op1`, `op2`, ..., `opN` are comparison operators, then `a op1 b op2 c ... y opN z` is equivalent to `a op1 b and b op2 c and ... y opN z`, except that each expression is evaluated at most once.

See [Python language reference](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in).

Comment: But only comparison by value between `1` and `True` will check out right? So `True is 1` and `1 is True` is False. and `True == 1` and `1 == True` is True.

Comment: Yes, `True`, `1` and `1.0` are all the objects of different type but with the same value. So objects identity operator `is` will always say that they are different. Other comparison operators will always compare their values.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you propably need a little cheat sheet to know the [order of evaluation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence). Most of these operators are on the same bracket and are therefore evaluated left-to-right. With this knowledge, the examples can be translated to their "real" meaning:

```
(3 < 5 is True is True) > 2 is (True is not False is True)
```

is equivalent to: (there actually are no `__is__` and `__not__`, because those are keywords that cannot be overloaded. It's for illustration purposes)

```
(3.__lt__(5).__is__(True).__is__(True)).__gt__(2).__is__(True.__is__(False).__not__().__is__(True))
```

I might spared out some details that are described [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence). The good thing is that you (hopefully) never write such complicated expressions that you need to check the documentation to know what it does.

EDIT: Nevermind, it doesn't work this way with comparisons. Comparisons get compared "all together pairwise", like described in viraptor's answer.

Comment: This is actually not correct. Have a look at my response. Expressions using only comparisons are treated specially. The page you reference says "(except for comparisons, including tests, which all have the same precedence and chain from left to right — see section Comparisons — and exponentiation, which groups from right to left)". Also "is not" is one operator in bytecode (whether you write `not 1 is 2` or `1 is not 2`).

Comment: I am aware of these inaccuracies, but I thought I'd be ok to let them slip for illustration. It's a whole section in the documentation for a reason.

Comment: What I meant is that `(3 < 5 is True)` is not equivalent to `3.__lt__(5).__is__(True)`. It's `(3.__lt__(5)) and (5.__is__(True))`.