# Please explain the output of this python code?

Tags: python

```
>>> 0 < 10 != 1 < 5
True
```

Why is it?? 0<10 is true. 1<5 is also true.True != True should be false . Then why the the output is True ???

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inequalities and Parenthesis in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33948574) & [What is the operator precedence when writing a double inequality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12658197)

Comment: @Trenton McKinney yes.. Thanks for sharing..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of operations priorities meaning of your expression is different. You need to put parentheses: `(0 < 10) != (1 < 5)`, to have what you want.

Otherwise your original expression means same as `(0 < 10) and (10 != 1) and (1 < 5)` which is not what you expected. (thanks to @TomKarzes)