# Why are booleans considered integers?

Tags: python

Python considers a boolean as an integer. Why?

```
>>> boolean = True
>>> isinstance(boolean, int)
True
```

Reverse the condition and ask Python if an integer is a boolean (obviously no), you get this:

```
>>> integer = 123
>>> isinstance(integer, bool)
False
```

Comment: You can read about the adoption of the `bool` type at [PEP 285](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0285/).  That should help clear up a lot of questions you have.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is in the documentation: [Numeric Types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=boolean#numeric-types-int-float-complex)

> There are three distinct numeric types: integers, floating point numbers, and complex numbers. **In addition, Booleans are a subtype of integers.**

`True` and `False` are numerically equal to `1` and `0` in Python, respectively.

Because bool is a subclass of int, as established above, `isinstance` returns true, [as documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance):

> `isinstance(object, classinfo)`
>
> Return `True` if the *object* argument is an instance of the *classinfo* argument, or of **a subclass thereof**.